# Android Studio 1.3.2 error when refreshing gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I generated `build.gradle` file from eclipse and import it to android studio.

However, it returns error after "refreshing gradle" :

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-1.12

This is the `classpath` :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-1.12'
```

This is what i have in my gradle directory :

```
C:\Users\user\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all
```

And this is what i have in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in my project's root :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

This is the error log :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find path to Gradle home directory
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.stopAllGradleDaemons(GradleUtil.java:462)
```

What should i do?

I have tried to use different internet connections, with/without proxy.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the gradle-plugin for Android and gradle.
They are different. You can find more info about the android plugin [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html)

With the `classpath` inside your gradle files, you set the version of the **android plugin for Gradle**.

Change your `classpath` using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

instead of:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-1.12'
```

In the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file you set the version of the **Gradle**. For example the 2.4 version.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use gradle 2.4, you can download it [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip). Then, extract the downloaded file into C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle. After that, open File > Settings from Android Studio. On the searchbox, type gradle and search.

[image]

Open `build.gradle` from the main project and type `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'` under `dependencies`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Finally, rebuild your project in Build > Rebuild project.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)