# Jenkins with Android Gradle Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1

Tags: android, svn, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am having trouble setting up an Android project on Jenkins using the Gradle plugin. I am getting the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'tablet_optimizations'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
     Required by:
         :tablet_optimizations:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

This is pulling a repo from SVN through a proxy, both of which seem to be set up properly. But maybe that could be an issue here. I am also pointing towards Gradle 2.4 for this project. I have seen a few issues similar to this on here but nothing seems to be helping. I will update with any additional info if needed! Please Help!!! Thanks!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your jenkins server has the latest android build tools?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599253/android-studio-1-3-2-error-when-refreshing-gradle

Comment: I have it pointing at the recent sdk. will that include the build tools?

Comment: @sasikumar classpath is correct as per that forum post and wrapper properties looks good as well however, I am not using the wrapper but an instance of grade on the machine

Comment: can you post your gradle file

Comment: Yes, it will. Are you using mavenCentral() on your gradle file?

Comment: plse refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715890/android-gradle-an-issue-occurred-configuring-root-project-android-studio

Comment: Please see my update. Mind you, this was all 100% working on a previous Jenkins server. I am setting up a new one and trying to use the same settings but I am not having any luck. It is not likely that I will be able to actually change any of the gradle project files for anything

Comment: You should shut down the vpn. then it works!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 403 error.

> Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being
>   configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource
>   by the client.

I had the same issue, because I was behind a firewall that just didn't allow the repository site.

Also your `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what the build.gradle looks like(see my edit). So this is going to be a proxy issue? Right now I am just running the server locally on localhost:8080 just for setup

Comment: Ok, so you have the Jenkins running in your own system? If so, could you run the gradle script locally via the command promt in your own system ?

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to 100% be an issue with the proxy config. Unfortunately the error is not too descriptive but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this turned out to be an issue getting through the proxy. The error message was a little misleading and made me believe this was a Gradle issue. I will post my config below in hopes it will help someone.

In the Manage Jenkins/Configure System page create a new "Environment Variable" under the "Global Properties" section:

```
name: GRADLE_OPTS

value: -Dhttp.proxyHost=<your proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<your port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<your proxy> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<your port> -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<your path to java jdk>
```

Maybe this can help someone with a similar issue!